# Get the type of a Gtk widget , by python

Tags: widget, gtk

I need a method that acts like this :

```py
def get_widget_type(widget_instance):
    return widget_type
    # widget_type : Gtk.Button , Gtk.Entry etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specific to GTK, but for Python in general: `type(widget_instance)`